# Return to the original page ElectronJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a while and I can not find it, so I decided to publish it to see if you can help me.

My code is the following:

```
exports.changePage = (link) => {
    mainWindow.loadURL(link + '/game')
}

exports.defaultPage = () => {
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'Pages/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }))
}
```

This would be in the Main.js, so, I would like to know if there is any way that when you load a url such as "http://google.com" when you click the search, run the defaultPage function to return to the original html.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 'load a url such as "http://google.com"? How can someone go to google.com from your electron app, unless you specifically lets him/her to?